# Mount webdav/davfs in RedHat OpenShift

Tags: openshift, redhat, webdav

Is it possible to mount a webdav file system in OpenShift? I have ssh access, but no root access so I can't install davfs or actually mount anything. I just need access to a webdav folder from OpenShift, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift online does not currently support WEBDAV, you will need to use SFTP or SCP to upload/download files from your gear(s).